# What's the structure of Rails' `schema_migrations` on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I don't have a Rails/MySQL set up at hand and I'm trying to check something. What's the structure of `schema_migrations` when Rails is connected to a MySQL database?

On PostgreSQL it's:

```
create table schema_migrations
(
    version varchar not null
        constraint schema_migrations_pkey
            primary key
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```